# spark using different versions of python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

trying to run spark using pyspark im getting the following error:

```
    An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (pi1 executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 473, in main
    raise Exception(("Python in worker has different version %s than that in " +
Exception: Python in worker has different version 3.9 than that in driver 3.8, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions. Please check environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON are correctly set.
```

**spark-env.sh :**

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop

export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
```

**.bashrc :**

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-arm64
export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native"
```

I tried specifying "python3.8" in the environment variables but same result

I don't thing I even have python3.9 :

```
find /usr/bin/ -name "*python*"
```

returning:

```
/usr/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3.8
/usr/bin/python3-config
/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-python3.8-config
/usr/bin/python3.8-config
/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-python3-config
```

my os is Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: I'm not an expert but it looks like the error is talking about your remote version of python not the local one so checking your version of python is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means you have a different version of python between your driver and the workers. You need to fix the version by specifying it in `PYSPARK_PYTHON` and `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON`. `/usr/bin/python3` is probably an alias to a certain version of python. replace it with its desired number e.g. `/usr/bin/python3.8`.